# Error while using javascript switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

when i click once on the button it displays the desired result,but clicking more than once displays the default statement value.

```
<script>
var result="pass";
function passfail()
{
  switch(result)
  {
    case "pass":
      result="you have passsed" ;
      break;
    case "fail":
      result="you have failed"
      break;
    default:
      result="you have entered wrong value";
  }
  alert(result);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use declaration `function passfail(result)` and then call with `passfail(result);`

Answer (score 1):

First call, your `result` variable have the value `pass`.
You then, inside the switch, replace the value with `you have passed`, `you have failed` or `you have entered wrong value`.
That is the value the `result` variable will have on the next call, hence it will go to the default case.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear,

First you define the variable result with the value "pass" once you clicked the button, the first case will be the selected one and it's going to modify the value in the result variable to be "you have passsed", once you clicked again the default case will be met.

Answer (score 0):

This is showing because value of result is being changed by "you have passsed".Next time it is searching for a case with value of "you have passsed",not "pass" or "fail"."you have passsed" case is not present in your switch statement ,that's why it is triggering the **default** one.